# check all parent when select a node in angular-ivh-treeview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, treeview

I want use angular-ivh-treeviewHow. this [sample](http://jsbin.com/tawaxozavi/edit?html,js,output) that i want to use. 
but this sample have a problem for me and it is when i select a node not selected all parent. How fix it?

Comment: Do you mean when you select a parent node it doesn't select all children?

Comment: @Yottatron no. when i select a node all parent checkd.

Comment: Ok, could you expand your question to include examples of what you need? It's difficult to understand.

Comment: @Yottatron this is my sample http://jsbin.com/cegipa/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least a couple options. You can create a custom template and listen for checkbox clicks then either: grab the parents of a clicked node and update their selected status, or emit an event telling parent nodes to change their selected status.

Here's an example of the former solution: http://jsbin.com/cegipa/6/edit?html,js,output

Note that when a child node is clicked its parents are updated to match its new state. This is accomplished by using the following template:

```
<span ivh-treeview-twistie></span>
</span>
<input type="checkbox" select-parents ng-model="node.selected">
<span class="ivh-treeview-node-label" ivh-treeview-toggle>
  {{trvw.label(node)}}
</span>
<div ivh-treeview-children></div>
```

With this directive attached to the checkbox:

```
app.directive('selectParents', function(ivhTreeviewBfs) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        var n = scope.node;
        ivhTreeviewBfs(stuff, function(node, parents) {
          if(n === node) {
            angular.forEach(parents, function(p) {
              p.selected = n.selected;
            });
            return false;
          }
        });
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And you could do something similar (and possibly more efficient) by passing events around.